# How to enable math in sphinx?

Tags: python, math, latex, python-sphinx

I am using [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/index.html) with the [pngmath](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/math.html#module-sphinx.ext.pngmath) extension to document my code that has a lot of mathematical expressions. Doing that in a `*.rst` file is working just fine.

`a \times b` becomes:

---

[image: works]

---

However, if I try the same inside a `*.py` file for example in a module documentation like so:

```
"""
a \times b
"""
```

I end up with

---

[image: does not work]

---

Furthermore no `amsmath` functionality seems to work, either.
What do I need to do, to also have math formulas in my `*.py` documentations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try putting a lower case 'r' before your docstring - like this:

```
def multiply(a,b):
    r"""
    returns a \times b
    """
    return a*b
```

I've never seen a raw literal string for a docstring before, but this will keep your \t from being interpreted as a `<TAB>` character.

Comment: Great. This solves the issue. Is there a way to tell sphinx not to look out for `<TAB>`s?

Comment: Sphinx is not your problem, it is the Python interpreter itself.  The leader 'r' is how you tell the interpreter to not process backslashes as character escapes, but leave them as just backslashes.  You could also double them up as in `a \\times b`, but this is really the purpose that the r"sldk\tlskjdf" syntax was intended for.