# Math expression in docstring is not rendered correctly by Sphinx

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, mathjax, docstring

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with this expression in my docstring. I'm using the `sphinx.ext.mathjax` extension in python sphinx v1.2b. The docstring:

```
.. math::

    w_k^* = \min_{w_k} \ell_k(w_k) + \lambda\left(\alpha||w_k||_1 
    + \frac{1}{2}(1-\alpha) ||w_k||^2\right)
```

This is what appears:
[image]

But it continues to generate this strange warning and not render the expression at all:

```
WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
```

Strangely enough, if I remove `\alpha`, `\left`, `\right`, `\frac` symbols, the expression renders fine without warnings. Not sure why `\lambda` would be supported and not `\alpha`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#math):

> Keep in mind that when you put math markup in **Python docstrings** read by autodoc, you either have to double all backslashes, or use Python raw strings (`r"raw"`).

This is needed so that LaTeX commands, such as `\alpha`, are interpreted correctly (`\a` and a few other sequences have [special meaning](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in a string literal).

This is the raw version of the docstring in the question, with triple quotes, prepended by `r`:

```
r"""
.. math::
 
    w_k^* = \min_{w_k} \ell_k(w_k) + \lambda\left(\alpha||w_k||_1 
    + \frac{1}{2}(1-\alpha) ||w_k||^2\right)
"""
```

Comment: Thanks this was indeed the problem. Should I always double all backslashes? I'm trying to follow the [numpy doscstring standard](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt). But they neither use raw strings or double backslashes.

Comment: Not all LaTeX commands clash with Python's special escape sequences. You noted yourself that `\lambda` worked. So it is not strictly true that you **always** must double backslashes or use raw strings (but it seems like good practice to do so, to save yourself from trouble).

Comment: I think it would be helpful to show the original equation: w_k^* = \min_{w_k} \ell_k(w_k) + \lambda\left(\alpha||w_k||_1 
    + \frac{1}{2}(1-\alpha) ||w_k||^2\right), and then show how it needs to be altered in order to have autodoc read it correctly inside of a Python docstring.

Comment: @Factor3: The equation does not need to be altered. All that is needed is an `r` in front of the docstring (to make the string "raw").

Comment: @mzjn, thanks.  So to clarify, the function :math:'\sigma_t \triangleq X + Y' would likely not render inside a Python docstring, and should be written as :math:r'\sigma_t \triangleq X + Y', and will render in a Python docstring properly?

Comment: @Factor3: the `r` should come immediately before the string literal. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8386407/407651.