# Sphinx math command in docstring is unknown?

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen

Example:

```
*{X}_{Q} -> {\round(t/Q*X)}_t
* {Q} = {q_1,...,q_l}
* {P} = {p_1,...,p_k}
```

causes me to get `warning: Found unknown command '\round'`

My [conf.py](https://github.com/openfheorg/openfhe-temp/blob/documentation/docs/conf.py) is the following.

Note: I'm using `autodoxygen` from Breathe

Comment: Are you using the `math` directive? You have "breathe" configured in conf.py so I presume that Doxygen is involved. A [mcve] would make it easier to help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the breathe directly in an `.rst` because the code is actually within a `.h` file. Also, I'm using the `autodoxygenindex` directive

Comment: Ahh, unfortunately (maybe fortunately) Doxygen along compiles and runs without any issues. It's only when I try to add in Sphinx + Breathe into the mix that things go sideways. I'm working on a MRE RN but I keep getting pulled into various tasks. I'll update later when I can. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure, but this might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16470758/407651